# Does $-1×-1=1$ in any ordered field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, axioms

Let $F$ be a field equipped with the addition (+) operation and multiplication (×) operation with axioms https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FieldAxioms.html

In general does $-1×-1=1$? In what cases would that not be the case?

Apologies if this question has been asked before, i've tried searching around but they usually just give analogies or are referring to a specific field like $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This is true in any ring with $1$.

Comment: you have $0\times 0 = (1-1)(1-1)$ and then you can expand and use all the axioms you can, and cancel, and see if you get what you want.